# Monitor SQL queries executed by a Delphi application

Tags: sql, oracle, delphi, debugging, dbexpress

I'd like to monitor SQL queries executed by my application while it runs.

I'm using a dbExpress connection to an Oracle 11g database under Delphi 2007.

This used to be possible under the BDE with the sqlmon.exe utility.

Is there a similar utility for dbExpress?

I've tried the Toad SQL Monitor, which logs two or three queries and then promptly hangs the application.  I can set up a full-blown Oracle trace, but that is overkill for everyday debugging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be able to monitor querys, you'll have to use a delegate trace driver.

Read [this link](http://www.drbob42.com/examines/examin91.htm), it gives more info on dbexpress 4 and delphi 2007.
Note for D2009 users: With D2009, you don't have to tweak ini files anymore, just use the object inspector, it gives the ability to stack up delegate drivers directly in the IDE.